# Return pointer-to-non-const using modified pointer-to-const

Tags: c++, constants

What's the best practice for returning a pointer-to-non-`const` from a function, where that pointer was obtained by modifying a (non-`const`) pointer-to-`const`? Like this:

```
NODE *top_level(const NODE *input)
{
  while (input->parent != nullptr)
    input = input->parent;  // NODE::parent is (non-const) NODE*

  return input;  // Compile failure: 
                 // Cannot convert from 'const NODE *' to 'NODE *'
}
```

I could `const_cast` the `const` away on return, which seems fine, but is there a better way?

Comment: Why does the parameter need to be const?

Comment: "is there a better way"? Yes, return const. Since your input is const, the output should be const too.

Comment: As top_level may return input, you should declare the parameter non-const or create two different implementations, one const, one non-const.

Comment: Why does it need to be const? Technically, it doesn't. The callers will always have non-const in hand. But the function doesn't modify `*input`, so why shouldn't it be const? In essence, the `const` here is not ensuring it can be called with `const` params; it's setting a no-mutation contract. Is that frowned on, semantically?

Comment: @Chowlett: what's frowned on is creating a function that lets callers write `const NODE my_top_level_node = { NULL }; top_level(&my_top_level_node)->parent = whatever_else;`. Your function smuggles away constness: the caller's code is const-unsafe but because of your function signature the compiler can't diagnose it. This is "more important" than documenting that the function doesn't change the input. Functions shouldn't modify pointer-to-const inputs, but it doesn't follow that all functions that don't themselves modify their inputs should take pointers-to-const.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best practice, at least in the standard library, is to provide `const` and non-`const` overloads. E.g. `std::strchr` is declared in `<cstring>` as

```
char *strchr(char *s, int c);
char const *strchr(char const *s, int c);
```

In a similar vein, functions like `std::map<T>::find` have overloads such as

```
iterator find(const Key& key);
const_iterator find(const Key& key) const;
```

Note that that there's no `const` qualifier on the first version, even though `find` itself has no reason to modify the `map`.(*) The point is that you get something out of `find` that *can* be used to modify the map, so by a kind of "transitivity of mutability", `find` cannot be `const`. The same situation applies in your problem, I think.

Alternatively, you could use a `const_cast`, but to me, that would feel like breaking a promise.

The funny thing about this situation is that, if you can guarantee that your function is never called on the top item of the tree (or whatever the input is), then there's no need for casts or overloads:

```
struct node {
    node *parent;
};

node *top(node const *n)
{
    node *p = n->parent;
    while (p->parent != 0)
        p = p->parent;
    return p;
}
```

compiles without any warnings.

(*) If `std::map` were implemented as a splay tree, `find` would have to modify it, but I don't think splay trees are allowed by the standard because of complexity guarantees.

Comment: Comment below duplicated: Mmm, I have done that before, with class member functions. This seems... different. The constness of the param isn't to enable const values to be passed in; it's contracting that the function won't mutate `*input` itself.

Comment: @Chowlett: that's similar to how `strchr` works in C: `char *strchr(char const *s, int c)`. That function is impossible to implement in pure C without casting the `const` away. The C++ standard library does not use `const` in this way, as it actually conflicts with the semantics of `const`.

Comment: So, in the case of a "non-mutation guarantee" `const`, you'd go with `const_cast`-ing?

Comment: @Chowlett: personally, I wouldn't put the `const` on the argument in the first place. I don't like `const_cast`, it feels like breaking a promise.

Comment: Would you just not indicate that the function guarantees non-mutation, then? (I agree about `const_cast` for the most part, by the way)

Comment: @Chowlett: I think I would, following . But see updated answer for why this is a dilemma and why `const`'s semantics are too simplistic for many situations involving pointer structures.

Answer (score 2):

[Edit: after both our edits, I think my answer and larsmans' are now the same but with things in a different order and different levels of detail for the different options. I encourage people not to bother upvoting this answer unless you see some important difference between it and larsmans'. I'll delete it if nobody finds one.]

*If* you're certain that the `const`-ness of `*input` should *not* imply that the function won't give you the means to modify some other node further up the list, then the fix is this:

```
NODE *top_level(const NODE *input_)
{
  NODE *input = const_cast<NODE*>(input_);
  while (input->parent != nullptr)
    input = input->parent;

  return input;
}
```

But this seems wrong to me, *because the function can return the exact same pointer value that was passed in*.

So, since it can give other code (albeit the caller) the means to modify its input, its input should not be marked as `const`. The "correct" solution is to provide const and non-const overloads, because that's how you avoid writing functions that "smuggle away constness", like the non-overloaded C version of `strstr` and other string search functions that return non-const.

If it weren't for the risk of removing const from a pointer to the same node (imagine that the input was somehow guaranteed not to be the top-level node, and imagine you're still sure that the constness of the first node shouldn't imply constness of other nodes in the list), then you could write it like this:

```
NODE *top_level(const NODE *input)
{
  NODE *result = input->parent;
  while (result->parent != nullptr)
    result = result->parent;

  return result;
}
```

Note that we no longer need the `const_cast`, it has disappeared when we added the assumption necessary to make the function itself a responsible const-safe citizen. The system works! ;-)

Comment: Did we just invent exactly the same example?

Comment: @larsmans: yep, and we were editing at the same time so neither of us copied the other. This proves conclusively that we're right, doesn't it? ;-)

Comment: Actually, I think the point "the function can return the exact same pointer value that was passed in" is an important difference. I can see the arguments that fudging the const-ness lets us "smuggle away constness", but _in this particular case_ I know that's legit - _except_ that I might put `myNode` in and get `myNode` out. So my takeaway is that what I'm doing is **Just Wrong** generally; but it's _specifically_ wrong here because I might get out what I put in.

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution, at the interface level at least, is to overload on `const`, providing two functions, `NODE const* top_level( NODE const* input )` and `NODE* top_level( NODE* input )`.  If you don't want to duplicate the code, you can then use `const_cast` to implement one in terms of the other.

Comment: Mmm, I have done that before, with class member functions. This seems... different. The constness of the param isn't to enable const values to be passed in; it's contracting that the function won't mutate `*input` itself.

Comment: @Chowlett But since the return value is related to the argument (in this case, at least)?  The C++ standard does just this for functions like `stdchr`, where it is faced with exactly the same problem.

Comment: @Chowlett: it's a useful convention that functions that don't modify the object take a `const*`, but it's *not* the main purpose of `const`. The main use of const is that (in the absence of casts) it propagates, so taking a pointer-to-const means (again, in the absence of casts) "I won't modify it and I won't let anybody else modify it either, whether by passing it to them or by storing it away somewhere for them to see later, or by return value". The design of `strstr` etc in C++ shows you that const-propagation is considered more important than hinting the action of the function itself.